# FixInputPort attempts to connect wrong port

Tags: drake

I have a custom `LeafSystem` that has input ports and output ports as follows

```
template <typename T>
MyLeafSystem<T>::MyLeafSystem() :
    systems::LeafSystem<T>(systems::SystemTypeTag<MyLeafSystem>{}),
    input1_idx(this->DeclareVectorInputPort("input1", systems::BasicVector<T>(1)).get_index()),
    input2_idx(this->DeclareVectorInputPort("input2", systems::BasicVector<T>(1)).get_index()),
    output_idx(this->DeclareVectorOutputPort("output", systems::BasicVector<T>(2), &TorqueCombiner::convert).get_index())
{}
```

I add it to my system via

```
auto my_leaf_system = builder.AddSystem(std::make_unique<MyLeafSystem<double>>());
// Connect one of the input ports of my_leaf_system
// Connect one of the output port of my_leaf_system
auto diagram = builder.Build();
```

For the remaining port, I wish to connect fix the input port for now.  I do so via

```
auto diagram = builder.Build();

std::unique_ptr<systems::Context<double>> diagram_context = diagram->CreateDefaultContext();
Context<double>& context = diagram->GetMutableSubsystemContext(plant, diagram_context.get());

context.FixInputPort(my_leaf_system->get_second_input_port().get_index(), Vector1d::Zero());
```

However, it throws a `std::logic_error` when I run `FixInputPort`

```
terminate called after throwing an instance of 'std::logic_error'
  what():  System::FixInputPortTypeCheck(): expected value of type drake::geometry::QueryObject<double> for input port 'geometry_query' (index 0) but the actual type was drake::systems::BasicVector<double>. (System ::_::drake/multibody/MultibodyPlant@000055e087146ec0)
```

The strange thing is

```
int(my_leaf_system->get_second_input_port().get_index())) == 0
```

and

```
int(plant.get_geometry_query_input_port().get_index())) == 0
```

My plant is added as follows

```
auto pair = drake::multibody::AddMultibodyPlantSceneGraph(&builder, std::make_unique<drake::multibody::MultibodyPlant<double>>(0));

drake::multibody::MultibodyPlant<double>& plant = pair.plant;
drake::geometry::SceneGraph<double>& scene_graph = pair.scene_graph;

// Make and add the model.
drake::multibody::Parser(&plant, &scene_graph).AddModelFromFile(model_filename);

// Connect scene graph to visualizer
drake::geometry::ConnectDrakeVisualizer(&builder, scene_graph);

plant.Finalize();



auto my_leaf_system = builder.AddSystem(std::make_unique<MyLeafSystem<double>>());
...
```

Comment: Updated title to better reflect the source of my problem

Answer (score 2):

There are several inconsistent thing with your post.  For starters, the error message implies that the error is generated when attempting to fix an input port of multibodyplant (not your leaf system).  And the type of that input port is not a vector, so the error is clear.

Is suspect that you’ve crossed your wires (or pointers) somewhere.  Fixing a vector input port of a derived leafsystem should be aok — it’s extremely common.

Comment: Upon further debugging, I found out that `int(my_leaf_system->get_second_input_port().get_index())) == int(plant.get_geometry_query_input_port().get_index())) == 0`, I don't understand why that would happen..

Comment: In case it isn't already clear -- input ports are numbered from 0 in each subsystem.

Comment: I must be missing something.. If both of them are 0, how does `context.FixInputPort(0, Vector1d::Zero())` know whether it is to connect `my_leaf_system.input2` or to connect `plant.get_geometry_query_input_port()`?

Comment: I think my concept of `Context` is messed up.  I believe I should be using `my_leaf_system_context.FixInputPort` or `my_leaf_system->get_second_input_port().FixValue(my_leaf_system_context, ...)`  (btw, is there any difference between the 2?)

Answer (score 0):

The error I made is in

```
Context<double>& context = diagram->GetMutableSubsystemContext(plant, diagram_context.get());

context.FixInputPort(my_leaf_system->get_second_input_port().get_index(), Vector1d::Zero());
```

Here, I am using the `context` for the `plant` subsystem to `FixInputPort` on `my_leaf_system`.

The correct code should be

```
Context<double>& my_leaf_system_context = diagram->GetMutableSubsystemContext(*my_leaf_system, diagram_context.get());

my_leaf_system_context.FixInputPort(my_leaf_system->get_mip_input_port().get_index(), Vector1d::Zero());
```

Thx Russ, Sherm!